# How to stop H1 from filling whole div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm creating a theme for my wordpress. I'm trying to add a top menu, but the h1 is restricting the menu from being on the same line: [image: header] I want them to be on the same line.

This is the HTML/PHP:

```
<header>
    <h1 class='title'><?php the_title(); ?></h1>    
    <?php wp_nav_menu(
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
            'menu_class' => 'topmenu'
        )
    );?>
</header>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.title {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
}  

.topmenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.topmenu li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `hx` elements are 100% wide **by default**....either restrict the width or make them `display:inline-block` etc...that isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your CSS

```
h1 {
     display: inline-block;
}
```